# Groovy $getCallSiteArray implementation

Tags: groovy

I am using groovy 2.4.12 with Oracle JVM 1.8. I am trying to understand a bit how `groovyc` converts the scripts written by end users.

To that end I wrote this simple script:

```
println 'Hello World`
```

This was compiled to bytecode using `groovyc hello.groovy`. Finally, I decompiled the `hello.class` to get the following code:

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class hello extends Script {
    public hello() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    }

    public hello(Binding context) {
        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
        super(context);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        var1[0].call(InvokerHelper.class, hello.class, args);
    }

    public Object run() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        return var1[1].callCurrent(this, "Hello World");
    }
}
```

This looks like a typical Java class except I cannot figure out where `$getCallSiteArray()` method is defined. It is definitely not in this class and neither is it a `public` or `protected` member of `groovy.lang.Script`. So my question is where is this method implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use another decompiler to see it

```java
// 
// Decompiled by Procyon v0.5.36
// 

public class A extends Script
{
    private static /* synthetic */ SoftReference $callSiteArray;
    
    public A() {
        $getCallSiteArray();
    }
    
    public A(final Binding context) {
        $getCallSiteArray();
        super(context);
    }
    
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        $getCallSiteArray()[0].call((Object)InvokerHelper.class, (Object)A.class, (Object)args);
    }
    
    public Object run() {
        return $getCallSiteArray()[1].callCurrent((GroovyObject)this, (Object)"hello world");
    }
    
    private static /* synthetic */ CallSiteArray $createCallSiteArray() {
        final String[] array = new String[2];
        $createCallSiteArray_1(array);
        return new CallSiteArray((Class)A.class, array);
    }
    
    private static /* synthetic */ CallSite[] $getCallSiteArray() {
        CallSiteArray $createCallSiteArray;
        if (A.$callSiteArray == null || ($createCallSiteArray = A.$callSiteArray.get()) == null) {
            $createCallSiteArray = $createCallSiteArray();
            A.$callSiteArray = new SoftReference($createCallSiteArray);
        }
        return $createCallSiteArray.array;
    }
}
```